# how can disable navigation button after reached on the last slide in javascript

Tags: javascript

the function is as under, want to stop or disable up arrow when slider is at last record and disable down arrow when slider is at first record.

```
upArrow.onclick = function(){
            if(x > "-900"){
                x = x - 300;
                slide.style.top = x + "px";
            }
            downArrow.onclick = function(){
                if(x < 0){
                    x = x + 300;
                    slide.style.top = x + "px";                
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the arrow by changing its pointer events and color when it reaches the desired value, for example:

```
upArrow.onclick = function(){
    if(x < 0){
        x = x + 300;
        slide.style.top = x + "px";
        downArrow.style.pointerEvents = "";
        downArrow.style.backgroundColor = "";
        if (x == 0) {
            upArrow.style.pointerEvents = "none";
            upArrow.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
        }
    }
}
downArrow.onclick = function(){
    if(x > -900){
        x = x - 300;
        slide.style.top = x + "px";
        upArrow.style.pointerEvents = "";
        upArrow.style.backgroundColor = "";
        if (x == -900) {
            downArrow.style.pointerEvents = "none";
            downArrow.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I did a little rewrite to the code to what I see more meaningful.